# Loop through an array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

I would like to know, how to loop through a array of int to get its value and set its value. I know how to use the for loop to to get instantly, but I am not sure how it works, when I am using in user created objects and esp using the get set method.

I am totally new to this and have very little guidance from my lectures. I hope you guys can assist to help me. This up to where I have done.

//point.h

```
class point {
private:
    int x[4];

public:
    int getx();
    void setx();
};
```

//point.cpp

```
class point {
   point::getx(){
      // ??????
   }

   point::setx(){
      // ???????
   }
```

//main.cpp

```
 int main(){
     point objPoint;
     objPoint.setx(/* ???? */);
     ???? = objPoint.getx();
 }
```

Comment: Q: Why do you have two different definitions of class "point" (or "why are you re-declaring "class point" when you're defining the implementations of getx() and setx()"?  Q: Why doesn't "setx()" have an argument (the value you want to *set* x to)?  Q: Why "int x[4]"?  Q: What does any of this have to do with a "loop"???

Comment: It seems like the flaw here is logical as much as anything. How will `getx()` know which of the 4 values to return? How will `setx()` know which value to set, and what will it set it too?

Comment: _"have very little guidance"_ There are excellent books providing guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @Shep It can be done. Thats y i asked the question.

Comment: @rasul1719435 - what John said below is absolutely correct: "An array of Points works like this, Point pointArray[4];. You still write your Point class for a single point, then you declare an array of Points in main. You don't put the array inside the Point class."  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4 I understand, u see i need to create a array of point class which should take in 4 sets of x per object. So if i create 5 sets of point objects, each object should have 4 sets of x each. Thats y i need to implement the x as array

Comment: @rasul1719435 - Are you saying that your "Point" consists of 4 "X" coordinates ... and no "Y" coordinates?  That makes no sense.  Or are you saying that you need 4 "int's" to accomodate one coordinate?  In that case, you should probably have *two* classes: one for "Point", the other for "Coordinate".  IMHO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your `getx` method should return `int*`, not just `int`, and your `setx` should receive `const int*` as parameter. Second, in your point.cpp file you shouldn't redeclare `class point`.

```
int* point::getx() { //version with copying
    int* ans = new int[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        ans[i] = x[i];
    }
    return ans;
}

void point::setx(const int* y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        x[i] = y[i];
    }
}
```

Then you can use them like this

```
int y[4] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int* z;
objPoint.setx(y);
z = objPoint.getx();
```

Just don't forget to `delete[] z` when you're done.

Comment: Yes, right. `delete z` will also work in this case, but don't do that) My mistake, corrected answer

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you probably want something like more this:

point.h:

```
class Point{
private:
  int x, y;
public:
  int getx();
  int gety();
  void setx(int value);
  void sety(int value);
};
```

point.cpp

```
int Point::getx() { return x; }
int Point::gety() { return y; }
void Point::setx(int value) { x = value; }
void Point::sety(int value) { x = value; }
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Point objPoint;
  objPoint.setx(1);
  int x = objPoint.getx();
  cout << "x=" << x << endl;
  return 0
}
```

Even better, you might wish to define a constructor like `Point (int xvalue, int yvalue)`.

IMHO ...

Comment: Yes. but i would like to use array

Comment: An array of Points works like this, `Point pointArray[4];`. You still write your Point class for a single point, then you declare an array of Points in main. You don't put the array inside the Point class.

Comment: @john U see i need to create a array of point class which should take in 4 sets of x per object. So if i create 5 sets of point objects, each object should have 4 sets of x each. Thats y i need to implement the x as array. If i dont create arrays of x than how can impelement this?

Comment: @rasul1719435 OK I misunderstood you.